# STL, list, iterator

Tags: list, stl, iterator

Exscusme buy my English )))

I have this problem: 
I must iterate items in STL list with posible editing items: remove, add, edit.
This is my approach:

```
void MoveOnNewPlace(Tree& parent, Tree& child)
{

    Tree *temp=&parent;
    while(temp->GetParent()!=temp && temp->GetItem().GetChar()=='(')
        temp=temp->GetParent();
    if(*temp==parent) return;
    Tree newTr(child);
    newTr.SetParent(*temp);
    temp->GetSubNodes()->push_back(newTr); //(Tree(child,temp));
    parent.GetSubNodes()->remove(child);

}

list<Tree>::_Nodeptr ptr=nodes->_Myhead->_Next;
    unsigned int i=0;
    while(i++<nodes->size() && ptr!=0)
    {
        Prepair(ptr->_Myval);
        if(ptr->_Myval.GetItem().GetChar()=='[')
            MoveOnNewPlace(t,ptr->_Myval);
        ptr=ptr->_Next;
    }
```

Could someone tell me how I can do it in other way without explicity using _Myhead, _Myhead and so on. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `list<Tree>::iterator` and `list<Tree>::const_iterator`?

```
for (list<Tree>::iterator i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i) {
    ...do stuff with *i...
}
```

Comment: If I use list<Tree>::const_iterator then I get compilation error,
if I use list<Tree>::iterator I get runtime error, because items of list can be deleted and it cause memory access violation.